# kibana visualize range query not work

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I want to query integer range.I'm saying simply my concept is min <= field <= max so I gave it in Kibana visualize like field:(>= min AND <= max).I think this is right query but it didn't work sometimes.I have list of integer values are 9466,9577,24342,24355,24665.

I tried to like below

```
     field:(>=9000 AND <=25000)
```

It return 24342,24355,24665.This is not proper result.Output should come 9466,9577,24342,24355,24665.where is the problem happen.I don't know.Any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the Lucene [query syntax language](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_ranges):

```
field:[9000 TO 25000]
```

Comment: Can you show a document that you think should match? Also what is the type of your `field`?

Comment: The field name is time_value.Its datatype is a string.We stored the date as an integer in a time_value field.

Comment: Well if the datatype is a string, it will be hard to use a range query. You need to change the type to integer or long instead. The string world uses lexical ordering so that `25000 < 9000`

Comment: Ok.I will change its data type then I will try.Thanks for your solution

Comment: Once you do, make sure to also refresh your index pattern in Kibana.

Comment: Yeah sure.I will do

Comment: I changed the datatype of time_value as per you said.It works fine now.Thanks.